# How prove this $\sum_{i}r_{i}x^2_{i}+2\sum_{i<j}r_{i}x_{i}x_{j}=\sum_{i}(r_{i}-r_{i-1})\left( \sum_{j=i}^{n}x_{j}\right)^2$

Tags: summation

> let $x_{1},x_{2},\cdots,x_{n}$ be real numbers,and $0=r_{0}\le r_{1}\le r_{2}\le\cdots\le r_{n}$.
>   show that:$$\sum_{i,j}\min{(r_{i},r_{j})}x_{i}x_{j}=\sum_{i}r_{i}x^2_{i}+2\sum_{i<j}r_{i}x_{i}x_{j}=\sum_{i}(r_{i}-r_{i-1})\left(
>  \sum_{j=i}^{n}x_{j}\right)^2$$

a  book say this It's clearly? can you someone explain?

I know $$\sum_{i,j}\min{(r_{i},r_{j})}x_{i}x_{j}=\sum_{i}r_{i}x^2_{i}+2\sum_{i<j}r_{i}x_{i}x_{j}$$ is clearly,But 
$$\sum_{i}r_{i}x^2_{i}+2\sum_{i<j}r_{i}x_{i}x_{j}=\sum_{i}(r_{i}-r_{i-1})\left(
 \sum_{j=i}^{n}x_{j}\right)^2$$ maybe not clearly.

Thank you

Comment: Lol at your book.  I would recommend expanding both sides for n=3 or 4 until you believe it.

Answer (score 1):

This is an explicit (and invertible) change of variables for quadratic forms. Here it is with $n=4.$ I used $p=r_1, q = r_2, r = r_3, s = r_4. $ The inequalities on these are irrelevant; all that matters is $r_0=0.$

$$   
 \left(  \begin{array}{cccc}
  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
  1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
  1 & 1 & 1 & 1   
\end{array} 
  \right) 
 \left(  \begin{array}{cccc}
  p & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & q-p & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & r-q & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & s-r   
\end{array} 
  \right) 
 \left(  \begin{array}{cccc}
  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
  0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1   
\end{array} 
  \right)
  $$

$$   
    = \;  \left(  \begin{array}{cccc}
  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
  1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
  1 & 1 & 1 & 1   
\end{array} 
  \right) 
 \left(  \begin{array}{cccc}
  p & p & p & p \\
  0 & q-p & q-p & q-p \\
  0 & 0 & r-q & r-q \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & s-r   
\end{array} 
  \right)  
  $$

$$   
   = \;  \left(  \begin{array}{cccc}
  p & p & p & p \\
  p & q & q & q \\
  p & q & r & r \\
  p & q & r & s   
\end{array} 
  \right).   
  $$

Note that the inverse of
$$
 \left(  \begin{array}{cccc}
  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
  0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1   
\end{array} 
  \right)
  $$
really is
$$
 \left(  \begin{array}{cccc}
  1 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1   
\end{array} 
  \right),
  $$
which is how the minus signs show up when reversing the process.